# Access denied to setFactory by executing HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, ssl, permissions

My scope is to send an https message trusting all certificates from a Java application on an Embedded Linux Module with a JVM (IcedTea6 1.11, Java Version 1.6.0_24) on it (as Info I have no access to this Embedded Linux or to the JVM to make any changes, I can only put compiled java application on it).

I have only basic Java knowledge but I wrote from some examples found on the net an application that trust all certificates.
At the beginning I had an error on the line

> SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

and I found out that the problem was that the SunJSSE Provider was not implemented in the JVM.
My first step was to add the SunJSSE Provider

> Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

and after this if I read out the providers I can see that the adding was successfully and now I find the provider “SunJSSE version 1.6”.
The Trust all Certificate Class is as following:

```
public final class TrustAllCertificates implements X509TrustManager, HostnameVerifier
{
     public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {return null;}
     public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
     public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
     public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {return true;}
     public static void install()
     {
         try
         {
            TrustAllCertificates trustAll = new TrustAllCertificates();
            final SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustAll}, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(trustAll);
         }
         catch (Exeption e)
         {
            JatLog.writeTempLog("Error: " + e.getMessage());
         }
     }
}
```

Now I receive always the error

> access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission setFactory)

On executing the line

> HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

Someone has any idea about how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the SecurityManager blocks this. Try settings for a single connection:

```
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    TrustAllCertificates trustAll = new TrustAllCertificates();
    sc.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustAll }, new java.security.SecureRandom());

    URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    if (urlConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
        HttpsURLConnection uc = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection;

        uc.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        uc.setHostnameVerifier(trustAll);

        uc.connect();
        JatLog.writeTempLog("headers: "+uc.getHeaderFields());
        uc.disconnect();
    }
```

if that doesnt help ask the swedish guys to update security manager settings ;)

hth